# Replace nth occurrence to its reverse

Tags: regex, scala

Scala provides out of the box methods to work either with first or with all occurrences of the pattern.

**What is the best (or canonical way) to replace only nth occurrence?**

I can think of a couple of solutions but I do not really like any of them.

First one uses mutable var to track occurrences.

```
  def f1(str: String, pattern: String, occurrence: Int) = {
    pattern.r.replaceAllIn(str, {var c = 0
      m: Match => {
      c = c + 1
      if (c == occurrence) m.group(1).reverse else m.group(1)
      }
    })
  }

  println(f1("aaa bbb123, ccc456, ddd789, qqq1010 206z", """(\d+)""", 3))
```

Second one finds all matches, picks up the required and applies patch method for the String.

```
  def f2(str: String, pattern: String, occurrence: Int) = {
    val m = pattern.r.findAllMatchIn(str).toList.lift(occurrence-1)
    m match {
      case Some(m) => str.patch(m.start(1), m.group(1).reverse, m.group(1).length)
      case None => str
    }
  }

  println(f2("aaa bbb123, ccc456, ddd789, qqq1010 206z", """(\d+)""", 3))
```

Is there more concise/preferable or better way?

**Update**

Yet another approach with zipAll.

```
  def f5(str: String, pattern: String, occurrence: Int) = {
    val m = pattern.r.findAllIn(str).toArray
    val x = str.split(pattern)
    if (x.size>occurrence) m(occurrence-1) = m(occurrence-1).reverse
    x.zipAll(m, "", "").flatMap(t => List(t._1, t._2)).mkString
  }
```

Results of the performance test for functions f1...f5 with 1 000 000 executions and below function to measure elapsed time

```
  def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
    result
  }

Elapsed time: 6352446800ns
Elapsed time: 4832129400ns
Elapsed time: 3153650800ns
Elapsed time: 3501623300ns
Elapsed time: 6276521500ns
```

f3 seems to be the best (which is expected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your 2nd approach is a good one but I wouldn't bother with the `List` manipulations.

```
def f3(str: String, pattern: String, occurrence: Int) = {
  val mi = pattern.r.findAllMatchIn(str).drop(occurrence - 1)
  if (mi.hasNext) {
    val m = mi.next()
    val s = m.group(0)
    str.patch(m.start, s.reverse, s.length)
  } else str
}
```

---

**update**: You could also try this slight modification.

```
def f4(str: String, pattern: String, occurrence: Int) =
  util.Try{pattern.r.findAllMatchIn(str).drop(occurrence - 1).next()
  }.fold(_=>str, m=>str.patch(m.start, m.group(0).reverse, m.group(0).length))


f4("aaa bbb123, ccc456, ddd789, qqq1010 206z", "\\d+", 3)
```

It's a bit more concise (a single line) and somewhat safer (won't throw if `pattern` can't be compiled to a regex), but I'm not sure it's actually preferable.

Comment: Your function f3 is the best from the performance point of view. See results in the original post.